# Can Meson read the contents of a file

Tags: meson-build

Is it possible for Meson to read the contents of a file into an array or a string?  From [here](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/blob/master/docs/markdown/Syntax.md) a string can be split into an array, and an array can be looped over with `foreach`, but I haven't been able to find a way to get the data from the file to start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly no, you can use `run_command()` to get it from another tool/script though.

Answer (score 8):

### Update

Since Meson 0.57.0, you can use the [`read`](https://mesonbuild.com/Fs-module.html#read) function of the Filesystem module:

```
fs = import('fs') 
...

my_list = fs.read('list.txt').strip().split('\n')

foreach item : my_list
  # Do something
endforeach
```

Answer (score 6):

To complete @TingPing's answer, I usually do that:

```
  files = run_command(
    'cat', files('thefile.txt'),
  ).stdout().strip()
```

That method can also be used for something like:

```
  images = run_command('find',
    meson.current_source_dir(),
    '-type', 'f',
    '-name', '*.png',
    '-printf', '%f\n'
  ).stdout().strip().split('\n')
```

Don't forget that file referencing can be a bit imprecise with Meson, so you need to use one of those:

- `files('thefilename')`
- `join_paths(meson.source_root(), meson.current_source_dir(), 'thefilename')`

EDIT : For a more cross-compatible solution you can use python instead of `cat` :

```
files = run_command('python', '-c',
    '[print(line, end="") for line in open("@0@")]'.format(myfile)
).stdout().strip()
```

Comment: Does that work cross-platform? (Since meson is written in python, I suppose you could use the python module to invoke a python script instead…)

Comment: @Caesar No, it does not. For example, the ```cat``` is not necessarily available in Windows.

Comment: To be more portable, you may use python instead. I'm editing the answer for that.

Comment: I believe `@0@` should be used instead of `{0}` for substitution pattern in command string

Comment: Yes, mistake on my part.